# adding View class to the default layout

Tags: android, view

I'm new to Android development.
I have a class DrawView that extends View, it's like a simple paint app

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas bitmapCanvas;
    int color;

    // Position of finger down
    float pX, pY;

    // Position of finger up
    float mX, mY;

    // Create new path
    Path path = new Path();

    // Is view initialized?!
    boolean isInitialized;

    // Create new paint
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    int begX, begY, endX, endY = 0;         


    //DrawView constructor
    public DrawView(Context context) {
            // Initialize new view
            super(context);
            setFocusable(false);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            this.setOnTouchListener(this);
            requestLayout();

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

            // There is no bitmap yet
            isInitialized = false;
    }

    //Initialize bitmap and canvas
    private void init() {

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight()/2, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            bitmap.setPixel(72, 72, Color.BLACK);

            // Create new canvas and set bitmap
            bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
            bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

            // ... set canvas background color
            bitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            // We're done with initialization
            isInitialized = true;
    }

    //Reset canvas
    public void reset(){
            bitmapCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);  
    }

    //Handle event 'onDraw'
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            // Check if initialized
            if (!isInitialized)
                    init();

            // Draw bitmap!
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    //Handle event 'onTouch'        
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            // Check event type

            switch (event.getAction()) {

            // Finger down
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(7f);
                    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

                    // Get current position
                    pX = event.getX();
                    pY = event.getY();                      

                    // Set beginning of path to (posX,posY)                     
                    path.moveTo(pX, pY);
                    begX= (int) pX;
                    begY = (int) pY;
                    bitmapCanvas.drawPoint(pX, pY, paint);

                    break;

            // Finger moves
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mX = event.getX();
                    mY = event.getY();

                    // Set position of end of path
                    path.lineTo(mX, mY);
                    endX = (int) mX;
                    endY = (int) mY;

                    // Draw path
                    bitmapCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);

                    // Invalidate canvas (redraw the view)

                    invalidate();
                    break;

            // Finger up
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    mX = event.getX();
                    mY = event.getY();

                    if (mY == pY && mX == pX){                      
                        bitmapCanvas.drawPoint(pX, pY, paint);
                        invalidate();
                    }

                    path.reset(); 
                    break;

            }

            return true;
    }
}
```

In my default layout, I want it to contains DrawView and other elements (button, textview ...)

How can I split "default layout" to contains DrawView with these elements?
Thanks

edit:
Where should I put this code to make DrawView work correctly

```
public class Draw extends Activity {
DrawView drawView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    setContentView(drawView);
    drawView.requestFocus();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your view with it's full name to your layout.For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...>
<TextView.../>
<my.package.MyCustomView

    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<Button.../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here `MyCustomView` is name of java class that extends `View` and `my.package` is name of package that contains that class.You can see that you can add `LayoutParams` to it,as I added layout_height or layout_width.

**Edit:**

If you want to use your custom view in `XML` layout,you have to add at least this constructor to your class:

```
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Ahmad Alkurdi Add another constructor to your java class to solve your bug.Please see my edit.

Comment: thank you very much, it's done right, but I don't know why I can't draw any think in this view

Comment: @AhmadAlkurdi What is your problem?Can you see your custom view and it is blank or you can not see it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want actually but you can use any layout as per your requirement here is the simple layout which your your view and another views in split screen

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView /> <!--your textview-->
    <TextView /> <!--your textview-->
    <TextView /> <!--your textview-->
</LinearLayout>

<com.androidapp.DrawView android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will split the screen in equal size for your view and another view with nested `LinearLayout`

If you want to display your content with wrap size then just remove the weight if you display at top of your DrawView and use `wrap_content` in height or if you display at bottom than give them weight in 0.2 or o.3 whatever but in float

**Edit**
Define both constructor

```
public DrawView(Context context) {
        // Initialize new view
        super(context);
        initObject();
}

public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    initObject();
}

private void initObject(){
      setFocusable(false);
      setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
      this.setOnTouchListener(this);
      requestLayout();

      paint.setAntiAlias(true);
      paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

      // There is no bitmap yet
      isInitialized = false;
}
```

Comment: I faced this bug
Custom view DrawView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work

Comment: define your DrawView constructor with 2 as first context, AttributeSet